# Store multiple properties in Angular mat-list component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-list

When using the Angular 11 mat-list-option component, I can set the [value] property as follows:

```
   <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false" #data (selectionChange)="onSelection($event)">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let element of rawData" [value]="element.code">
            {{element.name}}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

With the code above, the page shows the "name" property from my list and sets the "code" property as the value. This way when the user clicks the item, I can get the code and send it to another component. I have two other properties (description, source) that I'd also like to store in the list item. What is the best way to store all 3 properties (code, description and source) so that they are easily retrieved when the user selects the item in the list?

Comment: you can store the whole object `[value]="element"` and then retrieve values you want in your another component

Comment: you may have to use [ngValue] to store the object instead of a property.

Comment: Hi godocmat, that worked perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Tim .. could you share your final solution? I need to store 3 values and get them when user select a option.

Comment: Hi Roberto, The final solution was the one suggested by godocmat, which is to change the code to [value]="element". Once you do that, you can use any property of the element object in the code.